# calling constructor of a class with a dictionary of arguments

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a class which has a constructor requiring three arguments. A function in my code has a dictionary with the keys being the exact names of the arguments and the values being their values. Is there a way to call the constructor using this dictionary so that the keys automatically match up? or is the only solution to manually put each value into the constructor parameters?

```
class ItemDrop {
   constructor(id,x,y){
        this.id = id;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
   }
}
```

and within another file

```
var params = {
    "id" : "2837",
    "x" : 50,
    "y" : 100
}  
var itemdrop = new ItemDrop(params) // how would i do this?
```

To clarify, I don't want to run

```
var itemdrop = new ItemDrop(params['id'],params['x'],params['y'])
```

unless there is no cleaner option since I will be doing a similar operation many times with many different classes.

Comment: Use `constructor({id, x, y}){`…`}` and call `new ItemDrop(params)`. See [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's guaranteed that the constructor is called with only the desired properties, then you can use `Object.assign` to assign all properties in the parameter to the instance (`this`):

```js
class ItemDrop {
  constructor(params) {
    Object.assign(this, params);
  }
}

const params = {
  "id": "2837",
  "x": 50,
  "y": 100
}

const instance = new ItemDrop(params);
console.log(instance);
```

To keep the three parameters to the constructor, there's no way around repeating each property name twice, and the properties from `params` will have to be ordered in order to spread them into the constructor properly:

```js
class ItemDrop {
  constructor(id, x, y) {
    Object.assign(this, { id, x, y });
  }
}

const params = {
  "id": "2837",
  "x": 50,
  "y": 100
}

const instance = new ItemDrop(...Object.values(params));
console.log(instance);
```

Comment: Is this possible without altering the signature of the constructor? I need it to take multiple separate arguments in other sections of code

Comment: I got this working using an if-else based on `arguments.length`. Thanks!

Comment: My understanding is that the specification doesn't guarantee that the order of `Object.values()` is `id`, `x`, `y`. So is that second solution really even an option?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It's guaranteed in ES6+ (insertion order), but not in ES5.

Comment: Oh, fair enough. I guess those versions would be moot then since `class` and `Object.values()` aren't even available in ES5.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide  object as a parameter to the constructor function

```
constructor({id,x,y}){
         this.id = id;
         this.x = x;
         this.y =y;
    }
```